# Linear functional on complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

y(x) : C --> R is not a linear functional because C is a complex vector space. I do not know why. Please explain me.
 I can see they are not linear functional by checking only. Is there any logic on it?
The problem is : y (x) : C --> R defined by y(x) = x1 where x = x1 + ix2
My attempt: let x = 1+i in C; t = 1-i in C, alpha1 = 1; alpha2 = i
then y (alpha1 x + alpha2 t) = 2 which is not alpha1 y(x) + alpha2 y(t) = 1+i
The conclusion is y is not a linear functional.

Answer (score 0):

It is linear if you view $\mathbb{C}$ as a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, if you view $\mathbb{C}$ as a one-dimensional vector space over itself, it is not linear, because, for example, $i\cdot y(1) = i \neq y(i\cdot 1) = y(i) = 0.$ So the map does not behave linearly with respect to multiplication by a complex scalar.

Comment: What does $i\cdot y(1)$ mean? Isn't $y(1) \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0):

Find the linear function which maps the triangle with vertices at the points $(0,1,i)$ onto
a similar triangle with vertices at $(0,2,1+i).$

Comment: Sorry -(1+i)z+(1+i) is the answer.